# How to log in with your email address or nickname on a login form

Tags: php

How to log in with your email address or username

I have a login form that works great
The user must enter his username and password to connect to my site
But I would like to modify the code so that he can connect with his email address as well as with his nickname.

How could I fix this

Thanks for the help

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "base.php";
if (!empty($_POST["pseudo"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $pseudo = !empty($_POST["pseudo"]) ? $_POST["pseudo"] : null;
    $password = !empty($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : null;
    $sql =
        "SELECT pseudo, email,id,confirme, password,confirmkey FROM utilisateurs WHERE pseudo = ?";
    $datas = [$pseudo];
    //Execution de la requete
    try {
        $requete = $bdd->prepare($sql);
        $requete->execute($datas);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // en cas d'erreur :
        echo " Erreur ! " . $e->getMessage();
        echo " Les datas : ";
        print_r($datas);
    }
    $data = $requete->fetch();
    $row = $requete->rowCount();
    $userexit = $requete->fetch();
    //si le peusdo est bien dans la base alors on continue sinon on sort
    if ($data["confirme"] != 1 and $row == 0) {
        //pseusdo pas bon
        header("Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=divers2");
        die();
    }
    //else if
    //($data['confirme'] !=0 and $row == 1)//psuedo bon
    //{header('Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=divers3');
    //      die();}

    if ($data["confirme"] != 0) {
        if ($row == 1) {           
            if (password_verify($password, $data["password"])) {               
                         if (empty($_SESSION["link"])) {
                    header("Location: index.php?pseudo=" . $_SESSION["pseudo"]);
                    } else {
                    header("location: " . $_SESSION["link"]);
                }
                die();
            } else {
                header("Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=password");
                die();
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=already");
            die();
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=divers");
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  In the code shown, which operation is producing an unexpected result?

Comment: Why don't you change your SQL request like so : WHERE pseudo = ? OR email = ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: I may need to change this too $datas = [$pseudo];

Comment: Yes you'd likely need to change `$datas = [$pseudo];` to `$datas = [$pseudo, $pseudo];` so you've got two parameters to bind - one for each `?` in the query. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: "didn't work" isn't an error message or a useful problem statement. We can't help you based on that. Didn't work in what way? Was there an error? Did it not return any rows? Remember we can't see what input data you used or what's in your database, so we can't run your code, or work out for sure what the outcome would be.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
In my code the first condition I check if the pseudo is in the database if yes I continue
But how can I give an error if the email address is not in the database?

Comment: Aren't you already doing that in your code?

Comment: I would like the user to be able to enter either his nickname for the connection
or his email address

But I can't manage to do both conditions

Comment: I understand what you want, but you're being unclear about the specific problem. First you said that something doesn't work when you run the query to try and find the user based on either nickname or email, but you didn't say what the problem was. But last time you were saying the problem is how to show the user that the email wasn't found...however I can see that you already have code to show a message when the SELECT query returns no rows. So I'm really unsure what is or isn't happening when you run the code...remember, I can't run your code, and I can't see your data.

Comment: thanks for the help

For now in my form I just have two fields the first where the user can enter a pseudo

But I would like him to be able to enter a pseudo or an email address

and the second field is for the password

Comment: We already know that. It is not helpful that you just repeat what you want to achieve, over and over. Go learn some basics of debugging, instead of saying "didn't work, didn't work, didn't work." If you have no debugging skills whatsoever, then messing around with something as sensitive as a login functionality definitively isn't for you at this point.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();

//on recupere le lien link pour la redirection vers les autres pages
$link = !empty($_GET['link']) ? $_GET['link'] : NULL;

require_once 'base.php';

//si le pseudo et le pawword ne sont pas vide 
if (!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    //je recupere proprement des variables
    $pseudo = !empty($_POST['pseudo']) ? $_POST['pseudo'] : NULL;
    $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL;
    $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL;
 
    //préparation de la requête et des variables
    //$sql = 'SELECT pseudo, email,id,confirme, password,confirmkey FROM utilisateurs WHERE pseudo = ?';
    $sql = 'SELECT pseudo, email,id,confirme, password,confirmkey FROM utilisateurs WHERE pseudo = ? OR email = ?';
    //$datas = [$pseudo];
    $datas = array($pseudo,$pseudo);
    //Execution de la requete
    try
    {
        $requete = $bdd->prepare($sql);
        $requete->execute($datas);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // en cas d'erreur :
        echo " Erreur ! " . $e->getMessage();
        echo " Les datas : ";
        print_r($datas);
    }
    $data = $requete->fetch();
    // $row = $requete->rowCount();
  
  //je teste si le pseudo ou l'email sont bon 
    if (empty($data))
    {
        header('Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=MailPseusdoMauvais');
        die();
    }
    
    //je teste pour savoir si ils sont bien confirme
    if ($data['confirme'] != '1')
    {
        header('Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=ComptePasActive');
        die();
    }
    
    // si il est confirme je continue les tests 
    if ($data['confirme'] != 0)
    {
        
        //si l 'email ou le pseusdo sont bons on continue
        if (!empty($data))
        {
            //on verifie le pawword si il est ok on continue , sinon sortie
            if (password_verify($password, $data['password']))
            {
                //on definit et on cree les variables sessions
                $_SESSION['user'] = array(
                    'id' => $data['id'],
                    'pseudo' => $data['pseudo'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'confirmkey' => $data['confirmkey']
                );
                $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
                $_SESSION['pseudo'] = $data['pseudo'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
                $_SESSION['confirmkey'] = $data['confirmkey'];
                //on test la variable link si elle est vide  on va vers index
                if (empty($_SESSION['link']))
                {
                    header('Location: ./index.php?pseudo=' . $_SESSION['pseudo']);
                    //sinon on va faire la derniere page visitee
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    header('location: ' . $_SESSION['link']);
                }
                die();
            }
            else
            {
                header('Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=password');
                die();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header('Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=already');
            die();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: connexion-site.php?login_err=ComptePasActive');
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this a working answer? You posted code with no explanation. Did you solve it?

Comment: Thanks for answering your question. It could be improved further by concentrating on the relevant change and adding a text what exactly you did (SQL change?) and, if you know, why it fixed your problem.